# How to create charts from LandTrnder function in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, landtrendr

I ran the sample code found here: https://emapr.github.io/LT-GEE/lt-gee-outputs.html, which is supposed to generate an array of results:

```
[
  [1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, ...] // Year list 
  [ 811,  809,  821,  813,  836,  834,  833,  818,  826,  820,  765,  827,  775, ...] // Source list
  [ 827,  825,  823,  821,  819,  817,  814,  812,  810,  808,  806,  804,  802, ...] // Fitted list
  [   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1, ...] // Is Vertex list
]
```

I ended up generating an Image array and I would like convert it to an array dispayed above. I have attached a screesot of my result [image]

This is the code I used:

```
var startYear = 1985;
var endYear   = 2010;

var coords = [[-123.925, 42.996],
              [-122.327, 42.996],
              [-122.327, 43.548],
              [-123.925, 43.548],
              [-123.925, 42.996]];

var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(coords);
//console.log(aoi)

var run_params = { 
  maxSegments:            6,
  spikeThreshold:         0.9,
  vertexCountOvershoot:   3,
  preventOneYearRecovery: true,
  recoveryThreshold:      0.25,
  pvalThreshold:          0.05,
  bestModelProportion:    0.75,
  minObservationsNeeded:  6
};
for(var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {
  var img = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
              .filterBounds(aoi)
              .filterDate(year+'-06-15', year+'-09-15');
  
  img = img.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());

  var tempCollection = ee.ImageCollection(img.select(['B5_mean']));      
  //console.log(tempCollection)

  if(year == startYear) {
    var srCollection = tempCollection;
  } else {
    srCollection = srCollection.merge(tempCollection);
  }
}

run_params.timeSeries = srCollection;

var LTresult = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendr(run_params);

var segmentationInfo = LTresult.select(['LandTrendr']); // subset the LandTrendr segmentation info

console.log(LTresult)
//var LTarray = LTresult.select(['LandTrendr']);
//var year = LTarray.arraySlice(0, 0, 1);
//var yValues = year.toArray(['LandTrendr']);
//console.log(year)
console.log(LTresult)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a fairly sizable AOI which you run LandTrendr on. Each 30m Landsat pixels will get a separate model. It my opinion, it only makes sense to generate a chart or table for single pixels, or very small areas.

I would first change how you create your `srCollection` and use server-side iteration instead of your for loop:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
  .select('B5')
  .filterBounds(aoi)
    
var srCollection = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear)
  .map(function (year) {
    var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 6, 15)
    var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 9, 15)
    return collection
      .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
      .mean()
      .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis())
  })
```

Then you can extract the values for your AOI using `reduceRegion()`. Here, I only look at the centroid of your AOI:

```
var table = ee.List(segmentationInfo
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
    geometry: aoi.centroid(),
    scale: 30
  })
  .get('LandTrendr')
)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a5d66bbe6b5f723b76bcbc6e78c157c9

The title of your question and the body of your question ask different things - create a chart or a table. I answered the table question, as there isn't enough information about how you would want this charted.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. Can you also share how I can create a chart, since I was not able to change the produced list into an array and then chart it.